# For multi-robot simulation, do we need multiple multibodyplants?

Tags: drake

My current setup consists of two separate robots. I would like to know if its better to create 2 multibodyplants for 2 robots, or if its better to use one multibodyplant for the whole simulation.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are going to interact in any way (like manipulate the same object) then it is essential to use a single MultibodyPlant. If they are completely separate (connected only via the immobile World) then you could have separate MultibodyPlants but I don't know that there is an advantage to doing so.